# Cassadra nodetool status connection refused

Tags: cassandra

I tried installing cassandra 4.1 through Debian Package on ubuntu several times and once I get to the step nodetool status I get this error message
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

I tried to check the cassandra service, start it and restart it, I tried also some IPtables configuration and checked the yaml file but the problem still persist

Comment: So this sounds like Cassandra is not running. Check the `system.log` to see why. In fact, the service should have the last few lines of the log in its status: `systemctl status cassandra`

Comment: There was a problem with the memory size dedicated to JVM

Comment: I checked the system log and found this ERROR [main] 2023-12-22 12:32:44,707 CassandraDaemon.java:897 - Exception encountered during startup: If rpc_address is set to a wildcard address (0.0.0.0), then you must set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0 so I added broadcast_rpc_address with the public IPv4 address of the node in the yaml file retarded Cassandra but the same error persist I get  nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'