# Cassandra error : nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'

Tags: cassandra

I checked the system log and found this ERROR [main] 2023-12-22 12:32:44,707 CassandraDaemon.java:897 - Exception encountered during startup: If rpc_address is set to a wildcard address (0.0.0.0), then you must set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0, so I added broadcast_rpc_address with the public IPv4 address of the node in the yaml file and restarted Cassandra but the same error persists. I get nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'
I set JMX to no in env.sh file and I checked the security groups on AWS EC2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cassadra nodetool status connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692503/cassadra-nodetool-status-connection-refused)